# ManualResetEvent and Task Issue

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, mono

I've been working on a custom multi-threaded server that uses HTTP to communicate with clients.  To create new threads, I've been using the Task.Factory.StartNew() method. For synchronization, I've been using ManualResetEvent objects.

Here's the essence of the code:

```
namespace ThreadTest {
    class Program {        
        private readonly ManualResetEvent _event = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public void Start() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                int num = i;
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                    Console.WriteLine("Task {0} Started", num);
                    _event.WaitOne();
                });
            }  
        }      

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var test = new Program();
            test.Start();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

In the real code, the `_event` object would eventually have `Set` called on it to release the waiting tasks.

The problem I've run into is that this code works fine on my development machine (which is dual-core with 2 threads per core and using the MS .NET 4 runtime) but does not work on my server (which is single core with 1 thread per core and using the Mono 2.8 runtime).  The output on my development machine is:

```
Task 0 Started
Task 1 Started
Task 3 Started
Task 2 Started
Task 4 Started
Task 5 Started
...
```

While the server output is

```
Task 53 Started
```

My question is: What am I misunderstanding about the ManualResetEvent or Tasks?  Why does the TaskFactory continue to make tasks on the dual-core but not the single-core?

**Update:**

I just tried it on my dual-core (1 thread per core) mac laptop and I got the output

```
Task 97 Started
Task 1 Started
```

And then nothing.  I also tried it with Mono on my development machine (4 threads) and got:

```
Task 99 Started
Task 2 Started
Task 98 Started
Task 0 Started
```

So it looks like a bug with Mono.

Comment: One problem is that you're using the same event for all tasks.  Once any single task sets the event, all of the other waits are going to fall through immediately. Although that doesn't explain why your server only shows a single task starting.

Comment: @Jim Mischel: Yeah, in the real code, I have separate events.  I just don't get why, on a single threaded machine, I can only start 1 task at at time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug in Mono.  I [filed a report](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=671586) and it's now been fixed.

Comment: It's worth noting that a TaskScheduler implementation is not required to spin up Threads or provide any guarantees about the order in which Tasks will execute.  The only guarantees on ordering are defined using Task continuations, which the TaskScheduler is required to honor.  As such, it's not so much a bug in Mono as it is an inconsistency with the MS default implementation.  Your code shouldn't depend on the details of the implementation as long as they fulfill the relatively loose TaskScheduler contract.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as presented will never complete any of the tasks as the event is never signaled.  Ultimately it runs out of threads to allocate and it locks up.  The issue really is "how many threads does the task parallel library spin up under different CPU configurations when none of the threads can proceed" since that's what your code effectively measures.

The Task Parallel Library's default scheduler is based on `ThreadPool`, which uses a hill-climbing algorithm to adjust to the number of threads to maximize work item completion rate.  The algorithm takes into account how many cores you have.

There are better ways to use the Task Parallel Library to schedule work to happen once a Task has finished, ways that don't tie up threads, e.g `ContinueWith`.  What are you trying to achieve with the event construct?

Comment: The code was just the essence of the behaviour.  As it says in the question, in the real code, I actually call `Set` at some point and let those tasks finish.

Comment: But do you call it *before* thread starvation has set in?  TPL will sometimes run a Task on the calling thread, if that's the only thread that can set it, perhaps that's the issue.  The single core machine appears to have started 53 tasks before grinding to a halt and probably running task 53 on the calling thread.

Comment: I suspect the Mono implementation was actually putting Tasks into a stack or non-ordered collection and then grabbing one to start after several tasks had already been 'queued up'.  This might have been an attempt to provide 'fair' scheduling as opposed to FIFO dispatching to available Threads.